# How to implement JS tag to fire on click in eruby code?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, eruby

I need to get this piece of js to fire on a click event:

```
"_LT._trackEvent(_eventType.clickThrough)"
```

Need to add it to this eruby tag which already has an onclick event:

```
<%= submit_tag 'Send enquiry', :class => "BtnSubmit", :onclick => list_event(params[:item_key])%>
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What is list_event(params[:item_key]) returning here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onclick` attribute (and its value) will be turned straight into an HTML attribute, so if you want to have it run both the callback in `list_event` and this other callback, you'll need to join them together in such a way that the JS will run both.

I can see a few decent options for this:

1. Modify the `list_event` helper to also run `_LT._trackEvent(_eventType.clickThrough)`
2. Call your existing helper and tack the raw string on the end, as `"#{list_event(params[:item_key])}; _LT._trackEvent(_eventType.clickThrough)"`
3. Create another helper called something like `track_event` and call them as `"#{list_event(params[:item_key])}; #{track_event}"`
4. Create the `track_event` helper and then create a third helper to wrap them both, something like `list_and_track_event`, then call that instead

Personally I'd go with options 1 or 4 depending on the semantics of the two callbacks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will likely go with option 2. May i ask what you mean by '
The onclick attribute (and its value) will be turned straight into an HTML attribute'?

Comment: By that I mean there's no special process that goes on, Rails will just call `to_s` on whatever you pass in and dump that string out into the HTML, so you can craft yourself some (safe!) JS in a string however you like and pass that in (as `to_s` on a string just returns the string).